# How to get SP Currency field type value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a field with currency field type in my SharePoint list.I need to display all items in the list as a table. But for the currency field, it just displaying only the numbers. I need the value to be displayed as it is showing in the SP list. Like $432,98.00. My code is as shown below

```
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
    var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
    caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='" + columnName + "' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy></Query></View>");
    var ascItems = list.getItems(caml);
    context.load(ascItems);

//to get the value of each item based on field
var fieldType = fieldNames[i].get_fieldTypeKind();
if (fieldType === SP.FieldType.currency) {
                item = listItem.get_item(fieldNames[i].get_internalName());
            }
```

here, fieldNames is an array in which i have all column names. 
the item return the value as numbers like 43298. Please help

Comment: I would use regex

Comment: But in JSlink we could use get_item() function which will return the field value as it is in the list. So am expecting similar way in jsom without using regex.

Comment: Thanks @FlashThunder . Finally, i used regex to solve my problem. 
if (fieldType === SP.FieldType.currency) {
                var currency = listItem.get_item(fieldNames[i].get_internalName());
                if (currency != null)
                {
                    item = '$' + currency.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct currency format you can include and use the FieldValuesAsText.

Try something like this :

```
<script>
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");
function retrieveListItems() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("YourListName");
    var items = list.getItems(new SP.CamlQuery());

    context.load(items, 'Include(FieldValuesAsText)');
    context.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var item = enumerator.get_current();
            var fieldValuesAsText = item.get_fieldValuesAsText();
            var fieldValues = fieldValuesAsText.get_fieldValues();
            console.log(fieldValues.YourCurrencyFieldName);
        }
    }, function (sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_message());
    });
}
</script>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: when i use FieldValuesAsText, it will return only the values. But i need the entire field property like the getfields() function returns. I want to display each field as it is showing in the list and am doing it based on the field type of each field. var fieldType = fieldNames[i].get_fieldTypeKind();